# Integration of the multivariate Gaussian distribution.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I came across the following integral in polar form-
$$ \int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2(1-\alpha^2)}(r^2-2\alpha r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\bigg)rdrd\theta$$.

Is there any way to solve this integral or any substitution that we can make to solve the above integral? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the integral w.r.t. $r$ is of the form $u'(r)\exp(u(r))$.

Answer (score 0):

The inner integral is immediate because, factorizing the exponent you get an integral in the form

$$\int_0^{\infty}x e^{-Ax^2}dx=\left.-\frac{1}{2A}e^{-Ax^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty}$$

where

$$A=\frac{1-2\alpha \cos\theta\sin\theta}{2(1-\alpha^2)}$$